# Duplicate first name is not showing SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS report which gives total of monthly worked hours.
But when the employee has same first name, then his first name is not displaying. Only last name only showing in the report.

[image]

A grouping has implemented in the SSRS report design as below
[image]

Can anybody help me why the first name is not showing for 'Alexander'?

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate first names are displayed together because there is a grouping on "first_name" like it shows in your screenshot. Remove the grouping on first name and keep all the rows and it should be fine.

Right click on First_name in Row Groups section > Delete Group > Delete Group Only

Comment: you shoudl probably change your remaining group (`LastName`) to group by both first and last name too. Right click on the last name group in hte row groups panel and then properties, grouping and make sure first and last name are included. Also, please mark answers as accepted if they answered your question (the check mark under the vote up/down buttons)